# c# - FileStream with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFRING , ReadAsync() can read any num of bytes that smaller than buffer

Tags: c#, asynchronous, filestream

I read this article about file buffering: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-buffering

And I read the [requirements for using `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-buffering?redirectedfrom=MSDN#alignment-and-file-access-requirements).

This is my code:

```
FileOptions nocash = (FileOptions)0x20000000;
FileStream fs;
byte[] data;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\iP\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication32\ConsoleApplication32\bin\Debug\hello.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, 8192, FileOptions.Asynchronous|nocash);
    data = new byte[5968];
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await fs.ReadAsync(data,0,5968);
    byte[] ff = new byte[6] { data[5942], data[2435], data[2313], data[213], data[343], data[3698], };
    string hh = Encoding.Default.GetString(ff);
    Text = hh;
}
```

I read that:

> an application must meet certain requirements when working with files opened with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING. The following specifics apply:
>
> File access sizes, including the optional file offset in the OVERLAPPED structure, if specified, must be for a number of bytes that is an integer multiple of the volume sector size. For example, if the sector size is 512 bytes, an application can request reads and writes of 512, 1,024, 1,536, or 2,048 bytes, but not of 335, 981, or 7,171 bytes.

But I noticed that I can read any numbers of bytes (if it is smaller than the internal buffer) .

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: [It doesn't use your buffer](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,1943).

Comment: @HansPassant sorry friend  , i cant understand anything about this comments in this link , can you explain it to me if it won't bother you :)

Comment: Well, don't worry about it, `_buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];` is the important statement.  bufferSize is 4096, that keeps the OS happy.

Comment: @HansPassant Okay , but i still dont understand why when i put any numbers to read in fs.ReadAsync(data,0,num); which smaller than buffer , it works and it does not throw any error , contrary what the requirements of using FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFRING say , sorry If you already answered correctly but i dont understand quickly , so can you explain more to me ?